Logic for Tournament Bracket Matchups
I am making an eight team double-elimination tournament bracket and am currently working on the logic side of things.
I have eight teams and I am tracking their wins and losses. My goal is to separate teams with 0 losses (winners), 1 loss (losers), and 2 losses (eliminated-ers) - and create matchups within their category (teams with 0 losses would only play teams with 0 losses, teams with 1 loss would only play teams with 1 loss, and so on), until the championship which would obviously be between a "winner" team and a "loser" team with the first to 2 losses being eliminated.
I am currently thinking about using arrays to hold each category, but I don't know if there is anything else out there that I can use so I am open to suggestions :)
Since wins and losses are determined by button clicks, I have a simple button program I created :) (Currently it does have a bug where a team without a matchup after the first click is unclickable and considered undefined)


const teams = [{
  name: "Chaos Coordinators",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}, {
  name: "Sofa King Awesome",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}, {
  name: "The Nerd Herd",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}, {
  name: "The Laughing Stock",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}, {
  name: "Brainy Bunch Gone Wild",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}, {
  name: "Cereal Killers",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}, {
  name: "Jimmie Crickets",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}, {
  name: "The Mismatched Socks",
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0
}];

// DOM helpers 
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// App
const maxLosses = 2; // Max losses
const elTeamButtons = el("#team-buttons");
let winners = [];
let losers = [];
let eliminated = [];

const updateButton = (team) => {
  console.log("Updating button for team:", team.name); // Log button update
  const text = team.losses >= maxLosses ? "Eliminated" : `Wins: ${team.wins} - Losses: ${team.losses}`;
  team.button.textContent = `${team.name} - ${text}`;
  team.button.disabled = team.losses >= maxLosses;
  team.button.classList.toggle("is-eliminated", team.losses >= maxLosses);

  // Update color based on status
  if (team.losses === 0) {
    team.button.style.backgroundColor = "green"; // Winner
    team.button.style.color = "white"; // Ensure text is visible
  } else if (team.losses === 1) {
    team.button.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; // Loser
    team.button.style.color = "black"; // Ensure text is visible
  } else {
    team.button.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // Eliminated
    team.button.style.color = "white"; // Ensure text is visible
  }
};

const updateScore = (team, win, loss) => {
  console.log("Updating score for:", team.name); // Check if this logs correctly
  team.wins += win;
  team.losses += loss;
  console.log("Wins:", team.wins, "Losses:", team.losses); // Log new values
  updateButton(team);

  if (team.opponent) {
    team.opponent.losses += 1;
    console.log("Opponent losses:", team.opponent.losses); // Log opponent's losses
    updateButton(team.opponent);
  }
  groupTeams(teams);
  makeMatches();
};

const groupTeams = (array) => {
  winners = [];
  losers = [];
  eliminated = [];

  array.forEach(team => {
    if (team.losses === 0) {
      winners.push(team);
    } else if (team.losses === 1) {
      losers.push(team);
    } else {
      eliminated.push(team);
    }
  });

  console.log("Winners:", winners);
  console.log("Losers:", losers);
  console.log("Eliminated:", eliminated);
};

const makeMatches = () => {
  elTeamButtons.innerHTML = ""; // Cleanup
  console.log("Creating matches for:", winners, losers); // Log teams before creating buttons

  const logMatches = (group) => {
    group.forEach((team, i, teams) => {
      team.opponent = teams[i + (i % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1)];
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        console.log(`Match: ${team.name} vs ${team.opponent.name}`);
      }
    });
  };

  // Create buttons for winners
  winners.forEach((team, i, teams) => {
    team.opponent = teams[i + (i % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1)];
    console.log("Creating button for winner:", team.name); // Log team info
    team.button = elNew("button", {
      className: "team-button",
      onclick() {
        console.log("Button clicked for team:", team.name); // Log button click
        if (team.opponent) {
          // Assume each button click represents a win for the clicked team and a loss for the opponent
          updateScore(team, 1, 0); // 1 win, 0 loss for the clicked team
        }
      }
    });
    updateButton(team); // Initial button text
    elTeamButtons.append(team.button);
  });

  // Create buttons for losers
  losers.forEach((team, i, teams) => {
    team.opponent = teams[i + (i % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1)];
    console.log("Creating button for loser:", team.name); // Log team info
    team.button = elNew("button", {
      className: "team-button",
      onclick() {
        console.log("Button clicked for team:", team.name); // Log button click
        if (team.opponent) {
          // Assume each button click represents a win for the clicked team and a loss for the opponent
          updateScore(team, 1, 0); // 1 win, 0 loss for the clicked team
        }
      }
    });
    updateButton(team); // Initial button text
    elTeamButtons.append(team.button);
  });

  // Log current matches and waiting teams
  console.log("Current matches:");
  logMatches(winners);
  logMatches(losers);

  const waitingTeams = winners.concat(losers).filter((_, i, teams) => i % 2 !== 0);
  console.log("Teams waiting for a matchup:", waitingTeams.map(team => team.name));
};

// Function to Reset Teams to Initial State
function resetTeams() {
  // Reset wins and losses to their initial state if needed
  teams.forEach(team => {
    team.wins = 0;
    team.losses = 0;
  });  
  // Recreate matches with updated state
  groupTeams(teams);
  makeMatches();
}

// Initialize and Setup Event Listeners
console.log("Initializing matches...");
groupTeams(teams);
makeMatches();
console.log("Matches initialized.");

el("#resetButton").addEventListener("click", resetTeams);
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#team-buttons {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
  gap: 0.5em;

  & .team-button {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.3em);
    padding: 1em;

  &.is-eliminated {
      /* color: #f008; */
      color: red;
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Styled Buttons</title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <button id="resetButton">RESET</button>
<div id="team-buttons"></div>
  </body>



So I guess my question is three-fold:
What is the best way to separate the different types of teams (eliminated-ers, winners, and losers)?
What is the best way to push these types of teams into "rounds" based on the combined number of wins and losses (so I can have separate rules for a championship)?
And finally, am I going about this completely the wrong way? Any programming concepts I should look in to?
P.S. please please please do not write code for me. I am just starting programming and I want to learn :) so any nudge in the right direction whether it be documentation or other posts on the overflow or any other resources would be greatly appreciated :) this post has no intention of fleecing answers off of people.

In terms of separating the teams I would say the easiest approach here is creating arrays for each of the categories you stated, winners, losers and eliminated-ers. You can initialize these as empty arrays and iterate through your teams and add them to whichever category they belong. (Just realized this is exactly what you are doing)

As far as pushing them into rounds, I would first check that each of those created categories are even to ensure someone doesn't get left without a matchup. With that I would just use the categories themselves to make the matchups and if you want to make it more specific maybe using a differential variable, which would be the difference in wins and losses of a team and comparing those when making matches. A problem I kept running into was what would be the championship match, I would make sure that you accommodate for when there is only 1 team in each.

The above has mostly been continuing how you were thinking about but heres a little something different I think could be fun for you to implement.
Maybe instead of focusing on the teams you can focus on the tournament format. This would be having a tournament which has rounds in which matches are played. Each round can only continue after all matches within it are played. You start by making a bracket, this matches the teams randomly(or however you want to). With this you have 4 winners and 4 losers, with this you create 2 more brackets, one for the winners one for the winners. The losers that used to be in the winners bracket now move down to the losers, the winners that were in the losers bracket stay there and you create another bracket for them. Along with that you have the 2 people still in winners bracket play each other. You will essentially repeat this until you have made the 'winners bracket" and "losers bracket" (the arrays that contain them) have 1 team each, which tells you its time to run the final. Hope this was at least a bit helpful lol
